# Is returning under a `unique_lock` undefined behavior in C++11 based on CWG 1885

Tags: c++, c++11

The existence of [CWG 1885](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1885) seems to imply that until C++14, the following code was not guaranteed to be threadsafe

```cpp
std::string get_string()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(some_shared_mutex);
    return some_shared_string;
}
```

because the ordering of events on the exit of the function was not guaranteed - e.g. `lock` could be destroyed before the temporary to be returned is copy-initialized from `some_shared_string`, leading to a race condition.

This seems incredibly unlikely to be an issue in practice - one of the main advantages of `unique_lock` is that you're supposed to be able to do things like this, and I'd be a bit surprised to find out that an implementation didn't guarantee this even though the standard doesn't.

So my question(s)

- I'm not familiar with how C++ defect reports get retroactively applied, but it seems like since this is "CD4" status, that means it retroactively applies to C++14, but not 11; is that correct? The defect reports list on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) appears to say this also - 1579 applies to C++11, but 1885 applies to C++14
- Is this a practical concern? It seems like it'd be a bug in compilers supporting C++11 if they don't guarantee the expected ordering. Even though it could technically follow the standard without doing so, I can't see why anyone would want that.
- What about with really old compilers? If this *was* an issue at one point and got retroactively applied to C++11 by a specific implementation, how would I figure out which version of a compiler fixed it? I'm stuck with a toolchain that's still using GCC 4.8 - I don't see any bug report in the GCC bugzilla about this, but I can't find any confirmation that's it's *not* a potential issue either.

Comment: The old rule is too imprecise, but I would not really expect that any implementer interpreted it different from the fixed rule. You wouldn't even need the lock if that was a concern. Just returning a local variable by-value would have undefined behavior if the sequencing is not specified.

Comment: re terms, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html says "CD4: A DR/DRWP or Accepted/WP issue not resolved in C++14 but included in the Committee Draft advanced for balloting at the June, 2016 WG21 meeting." - it says when it was recorded, not what it applies to